# Get mysql connected with SpringBoot application in Openshift v3

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, openshift

I am not able to get my SpringBoot application linked with a mySQL POD in Openshift v3.

What I did so far:

- Got a basic spring boot application up and running in openshift v3.
- Added a mysql application. The pod is up and running without errors.
- Added the datasource configuration in application.properties of my spring boot app:

  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/${MYSQL_DATABASE}\
  spring.datasource.username=${MYSQL_USER}
  spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
- linked spring boot app with mysql db by executing the command:

> oc env dc shoppinglist -e MYSQL_USER=dbuser  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=dbpassword -e MYSQL_DATABASE=shoppingdb
>
> deploymentconfig "shoppinglist" updated

However, the spring boot pod is crashing because it cannot access the mysql db with the given user:

```
 2017-12-29 13:35:00.806 ERROR 1 --- [           main]
 o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial
 connections of pool. java.sql.SQLException: **Access denied for user
 ''@'172.17.0.7'** (using password: YES)
```

Somehow, the username is lost. I guess something with my oc env settings is weard? I have no glue...

I do not know what is wrong so far and appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: After adding the env variables, do you redeploy the pod? Because the env variables aren't immediately set, only after a fresh deployment does it pick up a new configuration.

Comment: Setting environment variables on a deployment config would in the normal case trigger an automatic restart. The issue is whether environment variable references in ``application.properties`` are expanded. Anyway, run ``oc debug dc shoppinglist`` and at the shell prompt run ``env`` to verify that the environment variables are passed into the container as first step.

Comment: I redeployed but it does not change the result.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton: 
I also tried `oc debug dc shoppinglist`. 
Response is: `Error from server (NotFound): pods "dc" not found`
I am wondering why this does not work, because when I execute oc get all, it returns besides others `dc/shoppinglist`

So syntax is correct, isn't it ?

Comment: Try ``oc debug dc/shoppinglist``. Usually commands will accept single combined argument, or as split values. Maybe that command doesn't for some reason.

Comment: @Graham: Thanks, in this way it works.
The env variables are listed. So, seems to be ok:
`...
MYSQL_PASSWORD=dbpassword

MYSQL_USER=dbuser

MYSQL_DATABASE=shoppingdb

...`

These are exactly the same I used in the `application.properties`
But still not working :-(

Comment: What are you reading that says environment variables are expanded in ``application.properties``?

Comment: - Are you sure the Username and the Password so provided is right ? 
- Do you have the authority (privileges) to perform the action. Authority takes the form of a specific privilege from a specified host?
- May be the problem was "WRONG PASSWORD".
- This Exception is also caused due to version mismatch of mysql db.. Make sure your pom.xml/jar version is higher than your mysql db version. Because higher versions are compatible with lower version's, but the same is not true for the inverse. Solution for spring boot is to override the spring boot dependency by adding 5.1.5.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy new year! And Thanks to everybody supporting me in finding the solution to my issue.
I learned a lot but at the end it was just a typo in my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/${MYSQL_DATABASE}\
```

It was propably a copy and paste issue (embarissing..)
I have overseen the **backslash** after `{MYSQL_DATABASE}`all the time.

Thanks again for any help!